# if i visit a url with mechanize then why its not counting the ip?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, mechanize-python, spynner

This is my code:

```
import mechanize
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

br.open("http://arn48.5gbfree.com/index.php")
print br.title()
time.sleep(7)
br.close()
```

I have used all most every possible way like normal webdriver,phantomjs,spynner etc and every code is correct but i couldn,t understand if i visit a url using this why my ip is not counted in the webpage. but when i visit the link manually its its counts the ip is it a program bug? Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: How do you check if it is logging your IP?

Comment: with a php and txt file